# Crear una landing page antes de la pagina de inicio de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy queriendo crear una landing page con html/css/js en donde cuando el usuario ingrese vea la landing y luego de un tiempo redireccione a la pagina de wordpress.
(todo en un mismo dominio)

---

- Intente tocando el .htaccess pero el problema es que me lleva al mismo lugar siempre:

---

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /project/index.php
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 DirectoryIndex ./landing/prueba.html

 # END WordPress
```

---

- esta seria mi landing page (hace una redireccion con js) tendria que ir al sitio wordpress pero se crea un loop siempre a la misma landing

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
  $(".logo").fadeIn(2000);
  $(".tlt").fadeIn(1000);
  $(".tlt2").fadeIn(1000);
  $('.tlt').textillate();
  $('.tlt2').textillate({
    initialDelay: 1000
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    url = "./";
    $(location).attr('href',url);
  },5000);
})

</script>
```

Comment: Haz la página en WordPress, no necesitas tocar `htaccess`.

Comment: Como seria hacer eso @toledano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo que uses el plugin "**Very Simple Splash Page**" (https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/very-simple-splash-page/) y a la pagina de splash le pongas con jQuery una redirección de URL con tiempo, por ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.tusitio.com/inicio";
    }, 10000);
});
```

o puedes usar el plugin "**Shortcode Redirect**" (https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-redirect/) y usas el siguiente shortcode:

```
[redirect url='http://www.tusitio.com/inici' sec=’10‘]
```